# C++ Calling an Uninitialized variable

Tags: c++, v8

I am looking at the following source code from v8, and I am confused by the handle_scope object. It looks like it is being called before it is being initialized. The [documentation](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1HandleScope.html#_details) specifies that it is a stack allocated Object. Is the default constructor called automatically for this object?

```
// Utility function that wraps a C++ http request object in a
// JavaScript object.
Handle<Object> JsHttpRequestProcessor::WrapMap(map<string, string>* obj) {
  // Handle scope for temporary handles.
  HandleScope handle_scope;

  // Fetch the template for creating JavaScript map wrappers.
  // It only has to be created once, which we do on demand.
  if (map_template_.IsEmpty()) {
    Handle<ObjectTemplate> raw_template = MakeMapTemplate();
    map_template_ = Persistent<ObjectTemplate>::New(raw_template);
  }
  Handle<ObjectTemplate> templ = map_template_;

  // Create an empty map wrapper.
  Handle<Object> result = templ->NewInstance();

  // Wrap the raw C++ pointer in an External so it can be referenced
  // from within JavaScript.
  Handle<External> map_ptr = External::New(obj);

  // Store the map pointer in the JavaScript wrapper.
  result->SetInternalField(0, map_ptr);

  // Return the result through the current handle scope.  Since each
  // of these handles will go away when the handle scope is deleted
  // we need to call Close to let one, the result, escape into the
  // outer handle scope.
  return handle_scope.Close(result);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the default constructor is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the object is default-initialized, which means that its default constructor will be called. Just like if you declare a `std::string`:

```
std::string str;
```

That `str` has still been initialized.

It is only for non-class types that default-initialization means no initialization.

Comment: Well, `int x;` in the same scope would also be initialized with an indeterminate values.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I mentioned non-class types at the end.

Comment: I meant "It is only for non-class types that default-initialization means no initialization" - no initialization here is incorrect.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore An indeterminate value is what an object has if it is not initialized: "if no initialization is performed, an
object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value."